# Can a LCD display work with swollen capacitors for a large period of time until briefly turned off?

Tags: capacitor, display

I am trying to figure out why would my very old SyncMaster 720N stop working after turning it off for a very brief moment. I've already had issues with it, I had to replace some capacitors and then it worked fine for more than a year.

I'm not asking about how to fix it. My question is: is it possible that display's capacitors would swell some time during its 20+ days uptime without going to standby of turning it off, but the display would still work with swollen capacitors until briefly powered off? Or would actual swollen capacitors cause the display to turn off spontaneously? I'm just wondering if it is worth it to take it apart once more to look at the capacitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the schematics of the TV, this can only be speculation, but - yes, it is possible for some damaged components to allow the television to continue to function but prevent it from starting up.  Startup is a very different set of conditions for a power supply (and other subsystems) than regular operation.

Of course, [capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) is far from the only thing that might have gone wrong with a 15 year old piece of consumer electronics.  And many of the other potential failures are impractical to diagnose without special equipment and knowledge of the design.

Comment: I tend to think it is the capacitors fault just because symptoms resemble very much my previous issue that was fixed by replacing capacitors. Though I checked that it is not the backlight, and that the display led reacts to some operating system's power management settings by changing its blinking pattern.

Comment: Cool.  Please post back and let us know the result :)